# How to tune up a servo and add protective clauses?

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I am working with an Arduino Uno, and have recently been given an assignment to use the servo motor.
The requirements are that I tune the pulse widths while comparing the 0 and 180 degrees. Secondly I must put in a protective clause to prevent it from going past the values. Any help at all is greatly appreciated. Thank you.
(Using the `servo.attach(pin, minpulse, maxpulse)` method, and `writeMicroseconds()` command.)

1. You may want to put in protective clauses in your code to prevent accidental driving of the servo beyond its intended range.
2. Write a simple program to tune up your servo’s min and max pulsewidths corresponding to 0° and 180°. Start by using 900 and 2100 in the `attach()` command, and perhaps sending the motor to 0°, 90°, and 180° delaying a couple seconds between moves for you to assess the quality of alignment.

My only ideas have been to manually fine tune it by checking when it does not turn any more.

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Asking here sounds like cheating.  Well, take a look at all the methods in the Arduino servo library.  See where you can simply write the delay in milliseconds?  See where you can simply read back the angle?  If it works, it's likely only an approximation, but you might be able to do your whole lab with no servo attached at all.  Of course you would have nothing to demonstrate.

Comment: You need to create some form of feedback system - something which, when you provide an angle to test will allow the Arduino (or you) to know the actual resulting angle and make the relevant adjustments. Automated could be a potentiometer that feeds back the angle (you will have to calibrate it yourself) or a simple protractor indicating the angle from which you read the value and feed it or the adjustments back in.  It's up to you how complex and automated you make it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I misinterpreted the question, a manual calibration would be enough, though the potentiometer idea sounds pretty cool.